# How to give a dinamicly created object in array a new property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an empty array for example called `const arr = [];` and when I click the button in page I want to create new Object inside this array, I do that with this following code line

```js
//add is button element
const add = document.querySelector(".add");

//value is input element
const valueInput = document.querySelector(".value");

add.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    arr.push(new Object)
    console.log(arr)
})
```

it makes object but I want to grab this Object and insert inside new property for example to called **"text"** and array should look like that

```
arr[{text: ''}]
```

**and every click I want to create new object in this array and property still must be text, inside the text I will put input value**

I tried on my own

```js
arr.push(new Object = {text})
```

```js
arr.Object.text = valueInput.value
```

but both of them give me left-hand error

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212) and how to [create objects](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer). `{text: valueInput.value}` is the object you want to push. Have you tried pushing that instead of `new Object`? `new Object = {text}` is invalid syntax. `arr.Object.text = valueInput.value` doesn’t make sense because your array doesn’t have an `Object` property.

Comment: you can use object literal also `arr.push({})`

Comment: you are welcome, you can use @ + username to mention someone. If you only type the username, they cannot be notified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the object literal with a property `text` and its value would be `valueInput.value`.

```js
//add is button element
const add = document.querySelector(".add");

//value is input element
const valueInput = document.querySelector(".value");

const arr = [];
add.addEventListener("click", () => {
  arr.push({
    text: valueInput.value
  });
  console.log(arr);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Insert text" class="value" />
<button class="add">add</button>
```